# Magento2: Select box as title in checkout as select

Tags: magento2, checkout, address

The title field in the checkout of M2 is only text field. Is there a possibility to use a select button instead to let the customer choose between "Prof" and "Dr"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can set options for Name Prefix from admin**

> Admin->Stores->Configuration->Customer->Customer configuration->Name and Address Options->Prefix Dropdown Options

[image]